# display button onclick pop up close button

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

Onclick button **"button1"** , we are displaying **pop up  bo**x and hiding **"button1"**.

but now we want to display the "**button1**" once we click on "**close**" button of "**pop up box**"

> pop up close button code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close">
<input type="button" onclick="showDiv()" style="display:none;" />
</a>

function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('aitcg-control-panel').style.display = "block";
}
```

> button1 code

```
<div id="aitcg-control-panel"><button>button1</button></div>
```

**Edit**

I tried this code : `document.getElementById('aitcg-control-panel').style.display = "block";` but still it didt worked for me....

Comment: please tell why negative marks , so i will improve ......

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted, so I don't know exactly the reason but I think points are two.
First one: you have a piece of HTML that on click of the button shows a div, which inside has a button. And then you say that on close you want to show that button? Isn't the button already there?
Second one: you should provide some code asking to SO and showing what's the issue. Here there is no code related to the issue

Comment: onclick of close button you can do like this document.getElementById('aitcg-control-panel').style.display = "block";

Comment: @Dinesh yeah, we can also set an interval and set the display block to that element another 10 times, just to be sure that it will be displayed if it was not in the first showDiv() function

Comment: onclick button button1, we are hiding the button1 , so on close pop up  i want to display button1 again [ once i click on button1, we are hiding button1. ]

Comment: on click you are showing a div with id `aitcg-control-panel` which inside has a button with a text "button1"

Comment: inititally button1 is displaying in site, once i click on button1 , than pop up box will display and button1 will hide, than once i close pop up box , i want to display button1 : http://prntscr.com/fbl24e

Comment: @rqwerty Take a look at the two answers below - do either of them do what you are looking for?

Comment: @rqwerty - to avoid downvotes, take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Down/Up votes are indicators of good or not so good questions.  In your case, you haven't really asked a question, and so it's not clear what you're asking.  Show us what you've tried, and explain why your attempt is not working, and explain what you expect the outcome to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into your website you've provided i found out that the elements you wanted to reappear were removed from the page.

Why don't you just keep the button instead? Because after saving the item it refreshes the page anyway.

There should be any javascript code in the module (aitcg) you've installed on your site that removes the elements aitcg-toolbox-{{somenumber}} and aitcg-control-pane from the page.

I hope this could be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for? I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do it, but your question wasn't super clear.

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('aitcg-control-panel').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('ShowDivButton').style.display = "none";
}

function hideDiv() {
  document.getElementById('aitcg-control-panel').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('ShowDivButton').style.display = "initial";
}
```

```css
div{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id='ShowDivButton' onclick="showDiv()">Open Div</button>

<div id="aitcg-control-panel" >
  <button id='ShowDivButton' onclick="hideDiv()">Close Div</button>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer is really very good , as i am not such a good in coding, i did't  find a solution with your answer..... I really appreciate your help , Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

I've sincerely not fully understood your question. But from what you've said, I'm assuming this is what you want:

```js
function display(a) {
  //Hide the button
  a.style.display = "none";
  //You need setTimeout for the code to wait for the alert to show the button again
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('ok');
    a.style.display = "block";
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="display(this);">Click me</button>
```

Hope it helps in some way and if this is not what you wanted, please reply.

Comment: your answer is really very good , as i am not such a good in coding, i did't  find a solution with your answer..... I really appreciate your help , Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

after giving link for you website. i can tell you the reason why its not working for you.

on click of save design you are removing code for **aitcg-control-panel** 
that's why you are not able to show it back 
proof: before clicking code for button div exists 
[image]

After click on save design 
proof: [image]
code is not there. that's why you are not able to show.

i debugged your code i found one function

```
 _getControlPanelHtml: function()
{
    if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
        var returnHtml = "";
                            returnHtml += '<div id="aitcg-control-panel" style="display:none">' +
            '<button onclick="return setproductlogin(\'null\', event);" class="aitcg-button apply-but" id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" title="{{apply_text}}">{{apply_text}}</button>' +
            '<button class="aitcg-button reset-but" id="submit-editorReset-{{rand}}" title="{{reset_text}}">{{reset_text}}</button>' +
            '</div>';
                    return returnHtml;
    }
    return '';
},
```

in this function they are returning '';

please change this function or other function to give you the same code what you had before clicking.

Comment: yes, that is correct function , can you please tell instead of `returning '';` what i need to use to get solution.....

Comment: is there any function for close button? if so, then from there you need to restore the editor code.

Comment: you can see close button html code in that plugin : `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close">`

Comment: please check the code for onclick of save design button. there may be you can find code for how they are removing?

Comment: can you please tell is i need to use this code in close pop up function : `document.getElementById('aitcg-control-panel').style.display = "block";` or is there any other code ?

Comment: this is code : `function setproductlogin(pid)
{
    document.getElementById("likeproduct_id").value=pid;
   jQuery("#productlistlogin").trigger("click");
}`

Comment: can you find click event function  for jQuery("#productlistlogin").trigger("click");  in you r source code you can check for click event on  productlistlogin. ??

Comment: in plugin, we have this code : `function setproductlogin(pid, event)
{    
    //alert(pid);    
    jQuery("#productlistlogin").trigger("click");
 
    return false;
}`

Comment: your answer is really very good , as i am not such a good in coding, i did't  find a solution with your answer..... I really appreciate your help , Thanks.....